# What are the best practices for Tekton implementation with multiple repositories with multiple deployments

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

We have multiple repositories that have multiple deployments in K8S.
Today, we have Tekton with the following setup:

1. We have 3 different projects, that should be build the same and deploy (they are just different repo and different name)
2. We defined 3 Tasks: Build Image, Deploy to S3, and Deploy to K8S cluster.
3. We defined 1 Pipeline that accepts parameters from the PipelineRun.

Our problem is that we want to get Webhooks externally from GitHub and to run the appropriate Pipeline automatically without the need to run it with params.
In addition, we want to be able to have the PipelineRun with default paramaters, so Users can invoke deployments automatically.

So - is our configuration and setup seems ok? Should we do something differently?

Comment: "run the appropriate Pipeline automatically" - should always the same pipeline be run from the same repository? Or can one repository have code for more than one pipeline?

Comment: We have a pipeline that gets the parameters on which repository to run and service name to change

Answer (score 0):

> Our problem is that we want to get Webhooks externally from GitHub and to run the appropriate Pipeline automatically without the need to run it with params. In addition, we want to be able to have the PipelineRun with default paramaters, so Users can invoke deployments automatically.

This sounds ok. The GitHub webhook initiates `PipelineRuns` of your `Pipeline` through a `Trigger`. But your `Pipeline` can also be initiated by the users directly in the cluster, or by using the [Tekton Dashboard](https://github.com/tektoncd/dashboard).